# e.preventDefault() is not behaving correctly

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down menu that is still triggering an href change even though I'm calling e.preventDefault().  This is how I have my jquery address change configured:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Setup jQuery address on some elements
    $('a').address();

    // Run some code on initial load
    $.address.init(function(e) {
        // Address details can be found in the event object
    });

    // Handle handle change events
    $.address.change(function(e) {

        var urlAux = e.value.split('=');
        var page   = urlAux[0];
        var arg  = urlAux[1];

        ....
     });
});
```

My drop down id looks like this:

```
<li id="search"><a href="#" class="drop" >Search</a>
```

my event handler for the drop down is below:

```
      $('#search').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).children(menuItemChildren).slideDown(0);
          $(this).hover(function() {
          }, function(){    
              $(this).children(menuItemChildren).slideUp(0);
          });
      });
```

Even though I'm calling e.preventDefault() on my #search element it still triggers an address change.  Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Probably because it's not a default action that you want to prevent. Look at [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<li id="search"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="drop" >Search</a>
```

Comment: this still triggers an address change

Comment: If that still triggers a change you have some other code set as a click handler i would think.

Comment: Pasting this into firebug at jquery.com $("body").append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="drop" >Search</a>'); and clicking the link has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a click handler on the `a` element, with a call to e.preventDefault()

```
$('#search a.drop').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble upwards, from child to parent. You're trying to prevent the default action on the `<a>` by calling `e.preventDefault();` on the parent `<li>`. The problem is that all actions connected with the `<a>` will fire before those connected to the `<li>` because of the event bubbling order I described in the first sentence. In other words, `e.preventDefault();` doesn't get called until after the event has already been triggered on the child.

You should bind a `click` event to the `<a>` element, and call `e.preventDefault();` from there.

Comment: so if I understand this correctly I need to call e.preventDefault on my parent <li> element?

Comment: No, you need to call e.preventDefault() on the <a> element. In your code sample you call e.preventDefault() on the <li> element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that MouseEvent e does not reference the a tag because you're binding the click event to the list element. You can check that using console.log(e.target). You may see that e.target is a list element. You can fix that by binding another event to

```
$('#search a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

But why use e.preventDefault() when you can just remove the href attribute? Do this and there will be no action taken upon click.